# mysql one or multiple data bases?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I was looking for an answer of modeling databases with MySQL, but couldn't find it.

What is the best practice, modeling 1 database and all tables & data in 1 repository, or split into multiple databases for handling each stuff like modules?

For example, I've 1 project with 55 tables, and would be much more while i'll develop with php a service in a domain; also started another project with 22 tables so far. And for both, I use users login, info and data differently; and like 6 or 10 tables & relations are organized in a layout (thank you MySQL scheme for supporting this). But what if I split both user handles into an external database and handle both databases with that one?

I just imagine if I split all my layouts into other databases, would be nightmare to program in php (spent months and have a lot of advance) but easy to give maintenance. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stick with one database and one database only unless you have specific reasons to violate that rule. Examples of valid reasons include:

- You've got a multi-tenant application and the instances of this application do not share data, so you spread them out across multiple databases to eliminate a single point of failure. Even then, these instances are just clones of the same basic schema.
- You need to shard your data across multiple instances for performance reasons or because of storage constraints that can't be solved in a cost-effective manner any other way. These shards share a schema, but only a portion of the complete data set.
- You need to create a replica or derivative set of data for data-warehouse and/or reporting reasons. These instances may have a radically different schema because they're optimized around read activities, not writes.

Unless you're doing something really involved, pushing the limits of MySQL, *stick with one database*. Your developers will appreciate it.

Fifty, sixty tables is not a lot of tables for a non-trivial application. Some applications have upwards of hundreds, but with the right naming conventions and good documentation this is not an issue. A good naming system means you can quickly search for what you want, plus lean on auto-complete via the tab key to get right to where you want to go.

Comment: For now, I'm the only one designer & developer. But I understand your point of view.

Comment: It is much, much better to have to pull the pin on splitting your database into multiple parts because you're out of options, something typically forced on you by scale (and success!) than to have some wildly over-engineered solution that was never really necessary. Keep it as simple as possible, but no simpler.

Comment: Another possible bullet item:  Different users can be `GRANTed` different (or no) access to different `DATABASEs`.  Sure, this can be done at the `TABLE` level, but db level seems cleaner.

Comment: @RickJames That's true, and important for some applications where you need to enforce absolute separation between two different data sets, but in practice most applications do not work this way, clients have no direct access to the database and all authentication is done in the application layer.